# Opamp circuit (amplifier with offset) degrades analog signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog, offset

I'm trying to amplify and offset a voltage from an DAC (0V to 3.3V) to -5V to +5V.
For this, I'm using a opamp (LM358) with dual power supply (-15V , +15V) with an offset and amplifier configuration.
[image]
The positive input is connected to the DAC output, while the power pins of the opamp are connected to -15V and +15V. I added 100 nF per power line and 47uF. C3 is not implemented in real world, I just inserted it if I ever need it. For testing, I changed R5 to 2.7 kΩ, R6 to 3.9 kΩ and R4 to 3.3 kΩ (so just divided by 10 each).
However, when I look at the signals with my oscilloscope, I get the following:
[image]
Yellow channel is the input signal to the opamp while the red one is the output signal. Green and blue are not important for this question, so please ignore them for now.
Since I'm more into software than analog hardware, I don't know exactly what to do to fix this. Any recommendations are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean magenta?

Comment: Yes i mean magenta as refered to red

Comment: Where was the op-amp sourced from? Could you show `-IN` waveform as well? DC voltage readings of all pins?

Comment: When you are testing it, what load is connected at the output?

Comment: I cant remember where I sourced the parts but I never buyed from untrustful sources, they should come from an serious electronics supplier for sure.
I tested the circuit with and without something connected to it. The output goes to another opamp, working as an impedence converter so there is nearly zero load. 
I can measure the negative input, however not at the moment as I'm not at home. But can bring it up at the evening.

Comment: Check the GND connection between the DAC side and this circuit.